# CPU usage with virtual machine versus physical machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

I sometimes run a Windows 10 virtual machine, using VirtualBox, on a Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.2 host. In the VM, I run MS Office, Google Chrome, and a few other light apps. Mint is not doing much, other than hosting the VM.

Now let's compare that to dumping the VM and just running the same apps on a physical Windows 10 machine.

How much CPU did I waste by using a VM? Enough to drain my laptop battery? If it is a desktop, enough to increase my electric bill?

Comment: Not much. I run a Kali Linux VM on my Windows 10 host machine and it does not overly deplete my battery. I still get several hours out of it (Lenovo laptop, SSD drive goes a long time on battery)

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely overhead on a VM. How much depends on the hardware and VM type.

Enough to decrease battery life on a laptop? Certainly.

Enough to be a measurable or significant increase to your power bill? Probably not more than a few pennies (assuming you're US).

Answer (score 0):

I am on my Windows 10 Pro laptop with both QuickBooks and Kali Linux running.  At idle, CPU is about 7% (normal) and VMware is using 0.1 or 0.2 % (very low)